# Team Foundation / SubVersion - Who has how much contrribution in the repository?

Tags: svn, version-control, tfs

Has anyone come across with something that tells who has how much contribution in the the given repository (SubVersion or Team Foundation Server)

e-g say there are 100 lines of code in 2 files; out of which khurram has written 30 lines and jhon has written 70 lines...something using TFS' Annotation and/or SubVersion' Blame (on each file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For subversion you could try the following link for [svn statistics](http://www.statsvn.org/)

It will give you more than you ever dreamed possible.

Comment: Have tried it with TFS through SvnBridge, and it worked great :)